# pandas: Convert Series of DataFrames to single DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, append

I have a pandas `Series` object with each value being a `DataFrame`. I am trying convert this into a single `DataFrame` with all of the `Series` values (individual `DataFrame`) stacked on top of each other. How can I achieve this without a loop?

A toy example below to generate the test object (`results`).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
numrows = 10000

def toy_function(x):
    silly_sequence = np.random.uniform(10, 100, (x+1))
    toy = pd.DataFrame({'ID':pd.Series(np.random.random_integers(1,20,3)),'VALUE':pd.Series((np.median(silly_sequence),np.mean(silly_sequence), np.max(silly_sequence)))})

    return toy

results = pd.DataFrame({'ID':range(numrows)})['ID'].apply(toy_function)
```

`results` is of `Series` type and each element is a `DataFrame` like so:

```
In [1]: results[1]
Out[1]: 
   ID      VALUE
0  17  40.035398
1   8  40.035398
2  20  66.483083
```

I am looking for a way to stack `results[1]`, `results[2]` etc. on top of each other to yield a DataFrame like this:

```
   ID      VALUE
0  17  40.035398
1   8  40.035398
2  20  66.483083
4  12  25.035398
5   1  25.135398
6  19  65.553083
...
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using `pd.concat`. At the very least, `pd.concat(series.tolist())` should work.

Its default is to take a list of pandas dataframes or series and return them tacked end on end. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: The `.values` is not needed. You can just pass `series.tolist()`

Comment: What if I want to expand/save the original index and the DFs have different length?

Comment: I tried this solution having some empty dataframes,unfortunately concat delete those empty dataframe. My solution was to fill those dataframes with nans before perform concat operation. Like this: 
if len(data) == 0:
    data = data.append(dict(zip(data.columns, [np.NaN]*data.shape[1])), ignore_index=True)

Answer (score 9):

Concatenate results and ignore your index while doing so:

```
df_stacked = pd.concat([r for r in results], ignore_index=True)
```